# python unboundLocalError: local variable 'HighestStockName' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program and am having a problem with one of my functions. When I try to run the program I get the following error about `unboundLocalError.` Can anyone help me with trying to fix this error?

```
def GetSale(Names, Prices, Exposure):
HighestStock = 0
for Stock in Names:
    TotalProfit = ((Prices[Stock][1] - Prices[Stock][0]) - Exposure[Stock][1] * 
    Prices[Stock][0]) * Exposure[Stock][0]
    if (TotalProfit > HighestStock):
       HighestStock = TotalProfit        
       HighestStockName = Stock
print("Highest selling stock is", HighestStockName, "with a ", HighestStock, "profit margin.")
```

Comment: Please edit your code formatting :). http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Sorry about that, is that better?

Comment: Better to follow the [Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008#prescriptive-naming-conventions)

Comment: `unboundLocalError` exception is telling you that your `if (TotalProfit > HighestStock): ` statement isn't entered, and the `HighestStockName` variable is not assigned.

Comment: You can avoid the exception by assigning `HighestStockName = None` right below where you set `HighestStock = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

If the argument 'Names' is None or empty, or if the `if (TotalProfit > HighestStock)` condition is false...

```
print("Highest selling stock is", HighestStockName, "with a ", HighestStock, "profit margin.")
```

Will raise the UnboundLocalError because HighestStockName gets assigned within the if block of the for loop.

Perhaps try initializing the value 'HighestStockName' underneath `HighestStock = 0` as such...

```
def GetSale(Names, Prices, Exposure):    
    HighestStock = 0 
    HighestStockName = ''
    for Stock in Names:            
        TotalProfit = ((Prices[Stock][1] - Prices[Stock][0]) - Exposure[Stock][1] * Prices[Stock][0]) *     Exposure[Stock][0]             
        if (TotalProfit > HighestStock):       
            HighestStock = TotalProfit     
            HighestStockName = Stock
    print("Highest selling stock is", HighestStockName, "with a ", HighestStock, "profit margin.")
```

Or just catch the UnboundLocalError exception and figure out what to do from there...

```
def GetSale(Names, Prices, Exposure):    
        HighestStock = 0 
        for Stock in Names:            
            TotalProfit = ((Prices[Stock][1] - Prices[Stock][0]) - Exposure[Stock][1] * Prices[Stock][0]) *     Exposure[Stock][0]             
            if (TotalProfit > HighestStock):       
                HighestStock = TotalProfit     
                HighestStockName = Stock
        try:
            print("Highest selling stock is", HighestStockName, "with a ", HighestStock, "profit margin.")
        except UnboundLocalError, e:
            # Do something after catching the exception
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider that if all of the calculations of **TotalProfit** end up being 0 or negative, you never enter the inner *if* block, and therefore, the **HighestStockName** is never assigned/defined.